# Unable to write to external storage

Tags: android

I'm trying to write data from the app's form into a .txt file but it won't work. I've put in an empty "record.txt" into the directory but nothing is written inside.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
```

MainActivity.java

```
String statement = textView.getText.toString();

File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
final File file = new File (root, "record.txt");

try {
     FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file);
     BufferedWriter buffwrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
     buffwrite.append(statement);
     buffwrite.newLine();
     buffwrite.flush();
     buffwrite.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't automatically create a file when you just create reference you have to check if the files exist or not
if(file.exists()) { ... }. Else 
 file.createNewFile(); 
And make sure you have necessary permissions

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for permission at runtime, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is consider a dangerous permissions.

[permissions overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

[request permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)